# How do I call information from a sub page of a specific parent page in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, parent-child

Ladies & Gentlemen, boys & Girls, Guru's, Geeks and Geniuses of all ages.

I am having a problem on my wordpress theme.

I am creating a website for a company which has an online shop. The hierarchy of the shop pages is as follows:

Shop
-Catagory Page
--Product Page

One of the category pages is called "Designs" which has a page ID of 22. What I would like to do in the sidebar `<aside>` of wordpress is display, as a link, the title and an image from the newest sub-page of the 'design' page. Each product page has an image defined using a custom field called "Product_Image".

I have found this code on stackoverflow which I've modified to display the data I need, but instead of just calling the latest sub-page of the design page it calls the latest page from the whole site.

```
<?php
   $args=array(
   'showposts'=>1,
   'post_type' => 'page',
   'caller_get_posts'=>1
   );
$my_query = new WP_Query($args);
if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
  while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
    <div>
      <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?>
        <?php  echo "<img src='" . get_post_meta($post->ID, "Product_Image", true) . "' />"; ?>
      </a>
    </div>
  <?php
  endwhile;
}
?>
```

I am completely new to PHP. I have only just started learning using "Tutsplus - PHP Essentials".

Could anyone help me modify this code so it only displays the information from the latest sub-page of the Design Page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a new argument to your query to only get pages that are a subpage of the design page.  So, modify your $args array to look like this:

```
$args=array(
  'showposts'=>1,
  'post_type' => 'page',
  'caller_get_posts'=>1,
  'post_parent' => '22'  // get pages that are children of the design page
);
```

Leave the rest of your code as is, and it should work.
For future reference, see here for all of the WP_Query parameters: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Query#Parameters

Comment: Wow as simple as that. Thank you very much.
I can't vote up the answer as I do not have a reputation of 15 yet.